# I am trying to convert 3D world coordinate to a 2D image coordinate in the form of pixels

Tags: coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, transform

I have a GeoTIFF file. I am trying to convert 3D world coordinate to a 2D image coordinate in the form of pixels. How can I do that?

Suppose, I can extract latitude, longitude and elevation data from the GeoTIFF file -- so can I use that 3D world information and project that to a 2D image coordinate?

here is the code that I have to convert pixels from geotiff to espg 46 format (degres)

```py
import rasterio

from pyproj import Transformer

transformer = Transformer.from_crs("epsg:3857", "epsg:4326")

geotiff = rasterio.open("pandas_east_asian_region.jpg")

lst_of_pts = []

#list of random pixel coordinates in an image
random_pixel_coords = [[130, 145], [185,560], [254, 360], [541,185]]

for pt in random_pixel_coords:

    crs_point = geotiff.transform * pt
    point = transformer.transform(*crs_point)
    lst_of_pts.append(point)

lst_of_pts = np.float32(lst_of_pts)

lst_of_pts
```

Comment: Well, this is some math but for this to become a good Q&A please include some concrete examples. What is the metadata of your GeoTIFF, what are the X/Y/Z coordinates you sampled, what are the properties of your desired 2D image? And why is Z relevant?

Comment: So, my GeoTIFF has latitude, longitude and elevation information. So, I am trying to take that lat, lon and elevation information and transform that 3D world coordinate into a 2D image pixel coordinate. I'm thinking opencv function (cv2.solvePnP) to get the translation and rotation vectors -- will that help?

Comment: Hi. Can you be more detailed? GeoTIFF format is not intended to store perspective data, there is not something like a pose in them. Do you mean a geotagged photo instead? How are you extracting lat, long and elevation data? Please, don't make assumptions. Pose a real and specific problem to which we can find a solution.

Comment: I am using the rasterio and pyproj library to extract the real-world latitude and longitude information in degrees (epsg:4326 format) from the pixel coordinates of my geotiff file which is in .jpg extension. My jpg extension geotiff file has metadata (i.e. latitude, longitude and elevation information). My goal is to take the 3D world info such as the latitude, longitude and elevation from the geotiff file (.jpg extension)  and plot it as a 2D image in pixels. So, essentially, what I'm trying to do is reproject the geotiff lat, lon, elevation data to a 2D image with lowest error possible.

Comment: All images are 2D. But sometimes pixel values are elevations or other variables instaed of colors. In your question we can see that you figured out lat and lon coordinates of some pixels from your .jpg map? How is elevation stored in it? How do you want to reproject it to other image?